# Format latitude and longitude axis labels in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, latitude-longitude, axis-labels, ggmap

I have a ggplot map, for example:

```
library(ggmap)
ggmap(get_map())
```

I'd like the axis labels to be automatically labeled as N-S / W-E: in the above case, for example, instead of lon -95.4 it should show 95.4°E.

I have tried to mess with the `scales` package and using `scale_x_continuous` and `scale_y_continuous` labels and breaks options, but I have not managed to make it work.

It would be awesome to have a `scale_y_latitude` and `scale_x_longitude`.

EDIT:
Thanks to @Jaap 's answer I got to the following:

```
scale_x_longitude <- function(xmin=-180, xmax=180, step=1, ...) {
    ewbrks <- seq(xmin,xmax,step)
    ewlbls <- unlist(lapply(ewbrks, function(x) ifelse(x < 0, paste(x, "W"), ifelse(x > 0, paste(x, "E"),x))))
    return(scale_x_continuous("Longitude", breaks = ewbrks, labels = ewlbls, expand = c(0, 0), ...))
}
scale_y_latitude <- function(ymin=-90, ymax=90, step=0.5, ...) {
    nsbrks <- seq(ymin,ymax,step)
    nslbls <- unlist(lapply(nsbrks, function(x) ifelse(x < 0, paste(x, "S"), ifelse(x > 0, paste(x, "N"),x))))
    return(scale_y_continuous("Latitude", breaks = nsbrks, labels = nslbls, expand = c(0, 0), ...))
}
```

Which works pretty well. But for some reason my R doesn't seem to like the degree symbol in front of the cardinal point... It is displayed as a simple dot, e.g. longitude -24 becomes `24..W`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such thing as `scale_x_longitude` or `scale_y_latitude` yet. In the meantime here is a workaround in which you specify the labels beforehand:

```
# load the needed libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)

# get the map
m <- get_map(location=c(lon=0,lat=0),zoom=5)

# create the breaks- and label vectors
ewbrks <- seq(-10,10,5)
nsbrks <- seq(-10,10,5)
ewlbls <- unlist(lapply(ewbrks, function(x) ifelse(x < 0, paste(x, "°E"), ifelse(x > 0, paste(x, "°W"),x))))
nslbls <- unlist(lapply(nsbrks, function(x) ifelse(x < 0, paste(x, "°S"), ifelse(x > 0, paste(x, "°N"),x))))

# create the map
ggmap(m) +
  geom_blank() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = ewbrks, labels = ewlbls, expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = nsbrks, labels = nslbls, expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size=12))
```

which gives:

[image]

---

To get the degrees in the functions, you can raise the `o` as superscript (which will circumvent the need for a special symbol):

```
scale_x_longitude <- function(xmin=-180, xmax=180, step=1, ...) {
  xbreaks <- seq(xmin,xmax,step)
  xlabels <- unlist(lapply(xbreaks, function(x) ifelse(x < 0, parse(text=paste0(x,"^o", "*W")), ifelse(x > 0, parse(text=paste0(x,"^o", "*E")),x))))
  return(scale_x_continuous("Longitude", breaks = xbreaks, labels = xlabels, expand = c(0, 0), ...))
}
scale_y_latitude <- function(ymin=-90, ymax=90, step=0.5, ...) {
  ybreaks <- seq(ymin,ymax,step)
  ylabels <- unlist(lapply(ybreaks, function(x) ifelse(x < 0, parse(text=paste0(x,"^o", "*S")), ifelse(x > 0, parse(text=paste0(x,"^o", "*N")),x))))
  return(scale_y_continuous("Latitude", breaks = ybreaks, labels = ylabels, expand = c(0, 0), ...))
}    

ggmap(m) +
  geom_blank() +
  scale_x_longitude(xmin=-10, xmax=10, step=5) +
  scale_y_latitude(ymin=-10, ymax=10, step=5) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size=12))
```

which gives the following map:

[image]

I used `geom_blank` just to illustrate the desired effect. You can off course use other geom's (e.g. `geom_point`) to plot your data on the map.

Comment: The answer's very good, thanks, but I'm not marking it as accepted as I'm looking for an automated approach, such as when doing `library(scales); p + scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)`     (see http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_continuous.html)... by the way my R doesn't seem to like the degree symbol in "°E"... it is not rendered correctly for some reason. Ideas?

Comment: @AF7 I think I found a solution for the degrees symbol. See the update.

Comment: Would it be possible to have the axis on the top and right as well? Adding `sec.axis = dup_axis()` to the return of the function only adds the Latitude/Longitude labels, not the ticks and numbers: http://imgur.com/a/BcQew

Comment: BTW, parsing `x` as `-x` for the West and South coordinates would be better.

Comment: Regarding Alfredo's comment, one could potentially also use a modulus to remove negatives (SQRT(x^2) unless someone knows a direct function); I'd have to play with this to check it works properly.

Comment: using this answer, is there a way to remove the negative sign? (for W & S)

Comment: @FishyFishies wrapping the labels vectors in `abs()` should work

Answer (score 3):

You can now use [metR](https://eliocamp.github.io/metR/index.html) package. It has `scale_*_latitude()` and `scale_*_longitude()` functions.

```r
# load the needed libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
library(metR) #new package

# get the map
m <- get_map(location=c(lon=0,lat=0),zoom=5)

# create the map
ggmap(m) +
  scale_x_longitude(breaks = seq(-10,10,5)) +
  scale_y_latitude(breaks = seq(-10,10,5))
#> Scale for x is already present.
#> Adding another scale for x, which will replace the existing scale.
#> Scale for y is already present.
#> Adding another scale for y, which will replace the existing scale.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>