# Do I need to find an alternative to rworldmap with impending retirement of maptools?

Tags: r

I am in the process of removing dependency of my R scripts on rgdal, rgeos and maptools - given their impending retirement. I am aware of various posts e.g. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sp/vignettes/retiring_rgdal_geos_1.html which have proved useful so far. But I am concerned about "unseen" dependencies.

For example, I use the rworldmap package for graphical mapping - which I understand uses maptools. My script output alludes to this when I load with library('rworldmap'). Do I need to find an alternative to rworldmap? - or will the maintainer of rworldmap remove the dependency? If the former, please can someone suggest a suitable alternative? I am using rworldmap primarily with spplot.

Many thanks
ricjoh

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution based on Robert Hijmans answer to a post with a similar question (not listed as a related post) [Latest / Current Worldmap as of 2023](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76505805/latest-current-worldmap-as-of-2023). It uses the geodata package.

```
library(geodata)
wmap <- world(path=".")
```

Then, based on the answer from andschar to the post https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/239118/r-convert-sf-object-back-to-spatialpolygonsdataframe and referencing part 2 of the vignette by Edzer Pebesma https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/vignettes/sf2.html,  I convert the SpatVector to SpatialPolygonDataFrame format using...

```
world_sp <- as(wmap, "Spatial")
```

This appears to work fine as input to:

```
borders = list('sp.polygons', world_sp, first=FALSE, lwd=2)
```

Which in turn feeds the sp.layout= argument in my spplot call.