# ggOceanMaps package not showing degree symbols in x and y axes labels for latitude and longitude values

Tags: r, ggplot2, spatial

I am using the package ggOceanMaps (and associated ggOceanMapsData) in R to make some maps with bathymetry. For some reason, no matter how I code/plot these, the degree symbol is not showing up on my plots. I am getting a weird square symbol instead.

```
#install 
#devtools::install_github("MikkoVihtakari/ggOceanMapsData")


#library
library(ggOceanMapsData)
library(ggOceanMaps)

basemap(limits = c(100, 160, -20, 30), bathymetry = TRUE)
```

The plot I get
[image]

Any ideas of what might be going wrong? When I try plotting it with my data/other regions I get the same issue. I have updated and restarted r and no luck.

In case this is helpful...

```
    packageVersion("ggOceanMaps")

 ‘1.3.4’

    packageVersion("ggOceanMapsData")

 ‘1.4’

    sessionInfo()

R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22621)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1 LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1 stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1 ggOceanMaps_1.3.4   ggspatial_1.1.6     ggOceanMapsData_1.4
 [4] lubridate_1.9.2     forcats_1.0.0       stringr_1.5.0      
 [7] dplyr_1.1.0         purrr_1.0.1         readr_2.1.4        
[10] tidyr_1.3.0         tibble_3.1.8        ggplot2_3.4.1      
[13] tidyverse_2.0.0    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.9         pillar_1.8.1       compiler_4.2.2    
 [4] class_7.3-20       tools_4.2.2        lifecycle_1.0.3   
 [7] gtable_0.3.1       timechange_0.2.0   lattice_0.20-45   
[10] pkgconfig_2.0.3    rlang_1.0.6        DBI_1.1.3         
[13] cli_3.6.0          rstudioapi_0.14    parallel_4.2.2    
[16] terra_1.6-17       e1071_1.7-11       raster_3.6-3      
[19] withr_2.5.0        rgeos_0.6-2        generics_0.1.3    
[22] vctrs_0.5.2        hms_1.1.2          classInt_0.4-8    
[25] grid_4.2.2         tidyselect_1.2.0   glue_1.6.2        
[28] sf_1.0-9           R6_2.5.1           fansi_1.0.3       
[31] sp_1.5-0           farver_2.1.1       tzdb_0.3.0        
[34] magrittr_2.0.3     codetools_0.2-18   units_0.8-0       
[37] scales_1.2.1       ellipsis_0.3.2     colorspace_2.0-3  
[40] KernSmooth_2.23-20 utf8_1.2.2         proxy_0.4-27      
[43] stringi_1.7.8      munsell_0.5.0     



    R.version
                              
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32               
arch           x86_64                           
os             mingw32                          
crt            ucrt                             
system         x86_64, mingw32                  
status                                          
major          4                                
minor          2.2                              
year           2022                             
month          10                               
day            31                               
svn rev        83211                            
language       R                                
version.string R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
nickname       Innocent and Trusting
```

I was able to find an alternative to be able to include degree symbols following [Jaap's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33302424/format-latitude-and-longitude-axis-labels-in-ggplot), but still curious why ggOceanMaps is not working.

Comment: This appears to be some sort of symbol problem introduced by a 4.2.2 version of R. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74940708/degree-symbol-in-plot-r-with-ggplot2-using-rstudio. Uncertain whether it has been fixed in newer R releases.

Comment: @Mikko Thanks for following up! I didn't think of downgrading the R version at the time. I just re-tried using R version 4.3.1 and degree symbols are working now.

Comment: Good to hear. Thanks for reporting! One worry less :)